# Is undecidable(complement of R) a subset of NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, undecidability

Is there an undecidable problem which is not NP-hard?

Comment: The title implies a very different kind of question from the actual post.

Comment: How so? I think they are identical. Perhaps you are referring to a previous title?

Comment: @Yuval, I think Vijay refers to the title before it was edited.

Answer (score 6):

If P=NP then any non-trivial set is NP-hard (other than the empty set and the complete set), so assume P$\neq$NP. If $A$ is a set and $f_i$ reduces SAT to $A$ in polytime, then $f_i$ must have infinite range. Otherwise, we can hardcode the relevant values of $f_i$ to get a polytime algorithm for SAT.

We can construct an undecidable problem which is not NP-hard using diagonalization. Let $f_i$ be an enumeration of all polytime reductions whose range is infinite. We construct an undecidable problem $A$ such that no $f_i$ reduces SAT to $A$. We will use $K$ to denote the undecidable set corresponding to the halting problem.

The set $A$ will be defined in stages, starting with a completely undefined set. In stage $i$, we find a string $s$ such that $f_i(s)$ is longer than any string on which $A$ is defined (here we use the fact that the range of $f_i$ is infinite). We define $A$ on $f_i(s)$ so that $s \in SAT$ iff $f_i(s) \notin A$. After all finite stages, we complete the definition of $A$ for each undefined string $s$ by letting $s \in A$ iff $|s| \in K$.

By construction, no polytime $f_i$ reduces SAT to $A$, and so $A$ is not NP-hard. On the other hand, $A$ is not decidable since $K$ reduces to $A$: we can decide whether $n \in K$ (for $n \geq 2$) by taking a majority of three strings of length $n$.

Comment: Hmm. I don't get the first statement. Why is any problem NP-hard?

Comment: If P=NP then a polytime reduction can solve any NP problem.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean with "infinite range"? I don't find any mentions of range regarding reductions.

Comment: The set $\{ f_i(\phi) \}$ is infinite, where $\phi$ ranges over all SAT instances.

Comment: How would you construct such an enumeration $f_i$? I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: There's a standard trick. You enumerate all pairs of $(T,p)$, where $T$ is a Turing machine and $p$ is a polynomial. You associate each such pair with a function $f(x)$ which consists of running $T(x)$ for $p(|x|)$ steps.

Comment: IIUC, this proof works only for input-transformation reductions. What if we allow Turing reductions?

Answer (score 2):

One example of an undecidable language that is not NP-hard, unless P = NP, is
$$
L = \{ 1^n : n \text{ is the natural number for a TM which halts on input } \epsilon\}.
$$
I have explained this answer through a more general theorem in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2691503/68107) on mathSE.