# Is proving NP-(in)completeness generally NP-complete?

Tags: undecidability, decision-problem, p-vs-np

Is even distinguishing between NP complete and incomplete problems an NP-hard problem?

Answer (score 2):

Distinguishing between complete and incomplete problems is not an NP-hard problem because it is not in fact, even a decision problem. A decision problem must be a set of strings. In this case, you have not specified an input and a set of strings that we wish to accept vs reject.

However, if you decide to represent a **"problem"** in a specific finitary way, then you can rephrase your question. For example,  one way to represent a problem is as a Turing machine. So you could ask, for example, is it NP-hard to determine on input a machine $M$, whether the language of $M$ is NP-complete?
The answer is yes, and in fact it is much worse than NP-hard, it is undecidable. (But take note that not all undecidable problems are NP-hard -- see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/is-undecidablecomplement-of-r-a-subset-of-np-hard/7677#7677).)

There are other ways to represent problems, though. One way to represent a problem is as a well-defined description in a certain **logic**, such as Peano Arithmetic (PA) or Set Theory (ZFC). That would be expressive enough to express any well-defined mathematical question about decision problems, restricted to decision problems that are definable within the logic in question.
And if the logic is *weak* enough (i.e., nowhere near as strong as PA or ZFC), you might end up with a set of definable decision problems for which NP-hardness is decidable.

Comment: Not all undecidable problems are NP-hard, indeed. However, problems whose undecidability follows from Rice’s theorem, such as here, *are* RE-hard (and coRE-hard), see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Proof_by_reduction_from_the_halting_problem .